# Why can we set mass to zero in Yukawa RGE derivation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In problem 12.1 from Peskin&Schroeder's book I have to derive the beta functions in massless Yukawa theory. What's the justification for setting mass to zero and what's the difference between massive and massless cases? Weinberg clarifies it in paragraph 18.2 but I don't understand this explanation.